# Parser and Lexer for Python-like language

Tags: c, parsing, lex

I have been playing around with a whitespace-sensitive lexer and parser for a Python-like syntax. The main goal is to *learn about parsers and lexers*.

The idea I had up until now is to make spaces insignificant in the lexer phase. For example, the input below will result in the output below.

```
if x:
  x
else:
  y
```

becomes:

`if x :{ x}; else :{ y};`

The problem I have with this is, I am unsure whether or not this is good output with respect to canonical solutions. One would expect the output to be as shown below; a single expression.

`if x:{x} else:{y};`

I have a parser as well, but that does not handle the shown output because it does not expect a semi-colon between the consequent and the alternative.

My current ideas to solve this are the following:

1) Preprocess the token stream and turn every expression in the form of `if e: {e}; else: {e};` into `if e: {e} else: {e}`, but that seems like a serious hack.

2) In the parser phase I can define that an `if` expression has a semi-colon after the consequent body. But that seems ugly to me, because if I want to parse single line `if's` as well I would need another case for those `if` expressions in my parser as well. The rules would look something like the ones shown below in my parser.

```
IF ::= if Expr : Expr else : Expr;
   |   if Expr : Expr; else : Expr;
```

My question is, what is the canonical way to lex and parse whitespace-sensitive languages? Is my approach completely wrong or is there no way to circumvent the current output I have?

### lex.x

````
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_DEPTH 10

int nesting = 0 ;
unsigned int indent_stack[MAX_DEPTH] ;
unsigned int first[MAX_DEPTH] = { 1 };
unsigned int level = 0 ;



void process_indent(char* line) ;

%}

PUNCT [-+*/=<>:]*
ID  [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*
INT [0-9]+

%option noyywrap

%%

^[ ]*\n       {/* Ignore blank lines. */}
^[ ]*[^ \n]+  {int last = yyleng - 1;
               process_indent(yytext) ;
               while ((last >= 0) &&
                      (yytext[last] != ' ')) {
                 unput(yytext[last]);
                 last-- ;}}

"("  {printf(" "); ECHO; nesting++ ; }
")"  {printf(" "); ECHO; nesting-- ; }

{ID}|{INT}|{PUNCT} {printf(" ") ; ECHO;}

[ \r] {}
\n    {}

<<EOF>>  { process_indent("EOF") ; return 0 ; }

%%

unsigned int white_count(char* line) {
  unsigned int count = 0 ;
  while (*line == ' ')
    count++, line++ ;
  return count ;
}

void process_indent(char* line) {

  unsigned int indent = white_count(line) ;


  if (nesting)
    /* Ignore indents while nested. */
    return ;

  if (indent == indent_stack[level]) {
    if (!first[level])
      printf(" ;") ;
    first[level] = 0 ;
    return ;
  }

  if (indent > indent_stack[level]) {
    printf("{") ;
    level = level + 1;
    indent_stack[level] = indent ;
    first[level] = 0;
    return ;
  }

  while (indent < indent_stack[level]) {
    level = level -1;
    if(level > 0)
      printf(" };") ;
    else
      printf("};");
  }

  assert(level >= 0) ;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  indent_stack[0] = 0 ;
  yylex() ;
  printf("\n") ;
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about canonical, but what I did was count the whitespace in some way (count number of spaces, or number of spaces / tab size, or number of tabs or whatever you choose to go with) and then add that to each token as another bit of data, and reset that count on every line break character.

Then when I parse stuff, I can just tell my if statement to expect else statements whose indent == if.indent etc.

I also once made the indent its own token, that can work, too. Really depends on what other syntax your language has.